# Variable in *ngFor need to be initialized or non-null?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have a complex object that isn't going to have data until I make an API call to populate it, which won't happen until the user clicks a button etc. Data from this complex object is shown using an `*ngFor` to iterate over a list which is a property of the object.

For example:

```
*ngFor="let hero of heroes.myList"
```

If the heroes object is defined but not initialized, e.g.:

```
heroes: MyComplexobject;
```

One way is to simply initialize heroes within `ngInit`, with something like this:

```
heroes = new MyComplexObject();
```

Is it that all variables need to be not only declared but initialized as well? Does `*ngFor` require that the heroes object in this case be both non-null and defined even before it's executed?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it need to be initialised? If all you have is a type declaration, the actual value is `undefined`. Even if it was `null`, how would that be iterated over?

Comment: Good point.  Even though it wont need to show anything until a user action takes place that makes an api call to populate the data, the template attempts to render upon the initial display, hence it makes sense that the variable needs to have been initialized.  Is there an option to guard from the variable being null or undefined?

Comment: <ng-container *ngIf="heroes?.myList"><ng-container *ngFor="let hero of heroes.myList"></ngcontainer></ng-container>